# Hide/clear cache of URLs on site with parameter

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, url-removal

A site I'm managing recently had a pharm hack and while the site is cleaned, there are still indexed pages with parameters. These pages still have the spammy meta titles yet clicking through goes to a 404. I'd like to get these removed but not sure how due to the parameters.

I've used the "removals" tool in Search Console and have seen "clear cached URL" options previously but seeing if anyone here has a way to use some kind of wildcard or regex to make this work so I don't have to put a whole bunch of individual URLs here.

Sample URLs

- http://example.com/?post_id=1320198
- http://example.com/?page=overnight-buspar

So questions are

1. Use temporarily remove URLs tool, if so can I do a wildcard/regex
2. Use the clear cache option, if so can I do a wildcard/regex.

   - Use clear cache for whole domain? Any guess on a timeline for the site to be recrawled? Is this too dangerous?

Comment: Where do you think they are being cached?  In the browser?  At the ISP?  By the server?  By the software (e.g. WordPress)?

Comment: @Steve well they are being cached in search results pages. Search console has an option to flush these to where it says "No page description available" until Google crawls it again and updates the title and description. [clear cached URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846#clear_cache_request&zippy=%2Cweb-page-url). If there is a better solution for removing/updating these I'm open to suggestions for sure